# Permutation of Elements of a Countable Infinite Set Such That No Element Repeats a Position

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ A = \{a_1,a_2, \ldots\}$, $B = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots\}$ and $C = \{c_1, c_2, \dots\}$ be three countable infinite sets. Let's say for each element $a_i \in A$ we want to pair an element $b_j \in B$ with an element $c_k \in C$ where $i$, $j$, and $k$ can be equal. Let's say we want to impose a restriction on this and that is if the pair $(b_j, c_k)$ has been paired before, we can't pair them again. Also every element of $B$ and $C$ has to be paired.

My understanding so far has been that we need $|\mathbb{N}|$ number of bijections from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Essentially what I thought about doing is to have a fixed permutation of $(b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots )$ and just permute $(c_1, c_2, c_3, \ldots )$ countably infinite times such that no $c_i$ ever appears in the same spot. I was thinking of somehow using the unique prime factorization theorem to ensure each element $c_i$ appears in a unique spot each time, but I can't figure out the bijection.

Comment: Fixing $i$, does every element of $C$ have to get paired with some element of $B$? Or do we just need an injection $B\rightarrow C$? If the latter, consider $b_j\mapsto c_{i+j}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes it has to be for every element of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question amounts to finding an injection $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} | f$ is a bijection$\}$. It suffices to instead find an injection $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} | f$ is a bijection$\}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are in a canonical bijection. This is quite simple: for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $g_n(k) = n + k$.